# putting columns in mysql in spark apache?

Tags: mysql, apache-spark

How can I put 2 columns one of character and one numbers in the MySQL using spark?

I tried to use the structType as well as case class so help me with these to do so plz?

Comment: Do you want to add columns or fill data in two columns?

Comment: I made a program to separate all characters and numeric values from files using Spark. The output for the data frame is in a single column characterise as I wished to have. Now I want to put the characters in one column in mysql table and within same table I want to put numbers in other column. how can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

i think you can't.

case class and Structype is used when you read data to structure your dataset.

The sql table should be already well formed if you want to insert data in with Spark.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to insert two columns in your table with type `char` and `integer`.

Assuming your data is in dataframe `jdbcDF`

> ```
> jdbcDF.write
>   .format("jdbc")
>   .option("url", "jdbc:mysql://host:3306/schema_name")
>   .option("dbtable", "schema_name.tablename")
>   .option("user", "username")
>   .option("password", "password")
>   .option("createTableColumnTypes", "name CHAR(1), num INTEGER")
>   .save()
> ```

[Spark docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#jdbc-to-other-databases)